# FlutterFlow: Drawer throws an exception

Tags: flutterflow

When reviewing the `Drawer` in `FlutterFlow` it opens up:

[image]

However, when trying to open it up from the `Test mode` it doesn't open and throws an exception:
[image]

Error message:

```html
dart_sdk.js:5397  Uncaught Error: Cannot hit test a render box with no size.
The hitTest() method was called on this RenderBox: RenderPositionedBox#cb851 relayoutBoundary=up2:
  needs compositing
  creator: Align ← Align ← Stack ← RepaintBoundary ← _DrawerControllerScope ← ListTileTheme ← Builder ← DrawerController-[LabeledGlobalKey<DrawerControllerState>#0696d] ← MediaQuery ← LayoutId-[<_ScaffoldSlot.drawer>] ← CustomMultiChildLayout ← _ActionsMarker ← ⋯
  parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0) (can use size)
  constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=834.0, 0.0<=h<=1194.0)
  size: MISSING
  alignment: AlignmentDirectional.centerEnd
  textDirection: ltr
  widthFactor: 1.0
  heightFactor: expand
Although this node is not marked as needing layout, its size is not set.
```

The part that says `Although this node is not marked as needing layout, its size is not set.` caught my attention, however setting the width didn't fix it:

[image]

Why isn't my `Drawer` being shown correctly in `Test mode`?

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the drawer a % size (like 70%), that worked for me. At least, then drawer renders in "run" mode. Hope that helps. -PB